# get CellIndex with grouping in kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We are using kendo grid in our project. We have some custom editors for every column. So, we are Getting the field names using this code to get the selected Cell(Column) name.

```
    edit:function(e){
           var grid = e.sender;
           var indexCell = e.container[0].cellIndex;
           var field = grid.columns[indexCell].field;
     }
```

It is working fine until we apply some grouping on the grid. After we grouped the grid, this code is not returning the selected Column Name. Please refer to this DOJO. Just apply grouping and click on the cell.

http://dojo.telerik.com/uLeQI/7

Please let me know if there is any other way to get the selected Column Name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below code.

```
edit:function(e){
                            var grid = e.sender;

                                        var indexCell = e.container[0].cellIndex;
                        if(e.sender.dataSource.group().length > 0)
                        {
                        indexCell =   indexCell - e.sender.dataSource.group().length;
                        }
                          var field = grid.columns[indexCell].field;
                        alert(field)

                      }
```

[Telerik DOJO link](http://dojo.telerik.com/uLeQI/9)

Answer (score 1):

Just try to change your edit handler to this:

```
edit:function(e){
     var grid = e.sender;
     var indexCell = grid._lastCellIndex;
     var field = grid.columns[indexCell].field;
     alert(field);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Prz!! It is Working!!